# Dataflow: Export to Bigquery from Pubsub RuntimeException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I am passing along a regular JSON to bigquery from pubsub via dataflow using the "export to bigquery" feature in pubsub.

However it worked for a second, meaning some of the entries go through to bigquery correctly. But now I am getting errors on the dataflow logs

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed:
>   [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"_comments","message":"no such
>   field.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:131)
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:97)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Insert failed:
>   [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"_comments","message":"no such
>   field.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
>
> ... MANY MANY LINES...
>
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:811)
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:127)
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:97)
>           org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown
>   Source)
>           org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.finishBundle(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:187)
>           com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.finishBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:407)
>           com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.finish(ParDoOperation.java:60)
>           com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:76)
>           com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1069)
>           com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:133)
>           com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$8.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:841)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a mismatch between the fields in Pub/Sub and the fields in Big Query.

Check if the name of your fields in both sides are the same. You can see more info about the Dataflow template in [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates?hl=en_US#cloudpubsubtobigquery)